# R plot legend not showing colors according to points

Tags: r, plot, colors, legend, points

So I have made a plot in R, with a lot of different colors indicating which of my 23 categories a point belongs to. The colors of points are added through a vector (stratumcol, which is a factor with 23 levels).

When I add the legend, trying to let that show the colors and their category, it seems they do not match (tested using ordihull, see picture below).

This is my plot code:

```
plot(pca_nmdsscores, type = "n")
points(pca_nmdsscores, col=stratumcol, cex=1.5, pch = 15)
legend("right","top",levels(stratumcol),cex=.8, col = as.numeric(stratumcol), pch =15, lty = 0) # pch = stratumcol
ordihull(pca_nmdsscores, groups = stratumcol,draw = "polygon", col ="purple",label = T, show.groups = "LateMoistRich")
ordihull(pca_nmdsscores, groups = stratumcol,draw = "polygon", col ="blue",label = T, show.groups = "MidWetPoor")
```

Here my Rplot should be visible. As you can see, my category "MaleMoistRich" connects the points with the pink-ish color, but in the legend this color is named "MidMoistRich".

The same for "MidWetPoor", connecting the mid-blue points, in the legend this color refers to "LateMoistPoor".

How do I solve this problem?

I tried looking for solutions, but didn't come across any that could solve it - including "unique" (which doesn't change anything, since my palette has been defined with 23 colors, so no need to recycle those anyway)

[Plot from R, showing legend and points color][1]

Ok - so since I'm a newbie I can't upload an image of my plot...

But see it here instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzn2y.png

/thanks

Edit:
The solution was to not use levels() on my factor! Not in legend = levels(stratumcol), nor in col = levels(stratumcol). Richard and DeveauP suggested levels might be the problem.

This created a new problem: my legen displayed the whole factor, not just the levels in it (but the colors corresponded to the correct point colors, which was the original problem).

this new problem was solved by using "unique()" instead of "levels()".

```
legend("Right","top",legend=unique(stratumcol), cex=.8, col = unique(stratumcol), pch=15, lty=0)
```

I found a solution

Comment: I see that you put "col = as.numeric(stratumcol)" in the legend, this may change the order compared to the factors (numeric 1 is not necessarily the first factor). What happens if you remove the as.numeric?

Comment: This doesn't change anything. I added it to try and fix it - which it didn't either :)

Comment: The problem might be with your use of legend. If stratumcol is a factor, as.numeric() will return factor codes rather than the colours. Also as.numeric(stratumcol) will give the vector in whatever order it is in rather than in the order corresponding to the levels().

Comment: Now I'm thinking - could the levels() indicater change the order that colors are added to the legend compared to just "stratumcol"?
Stratumcol is a factor with 129 rows, and the levels popping up at different times?
Hmm, it shouldn't..

Comment: May have found the issue: levels will order your factors. So levels(stratumcol) and as.numeric(stratumcol) may not be in the same order. -- 2 minutes late, Richard spotted the issue before me!

Comment: @Richard Telford
I tried removing the as.numeric, and it doen't make any difference. The colors are added in the same manner. So the points and the legend still doens't match. (or the ordihull doesn't)
It's just wierd, since all functions refer back to the same factor-vector.

Comment: But you are both right - levels() does change the order!

This is solved by removing the levels() part!

Unfortunately, I would prefer to fix it by ordering the color assignations in the same way as levels does, but it return an error.
Also - it's just because I liked the way levels ordered the legend..
Which I could come around in other ways.

Comment: If one of you want to post an actual answer I can probably figure out how to mark it as accepted answer:)

And thanks!

Comment: However! (sorry for so many comments)
Removing Levels() gives me another problem - it displays the whole factor, in it's complete length in the legend - so the plot cuts some off, as if something is missing. (and if I have less levels, the levels will just be displayed repeatedly) Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
legend("right","top",legend = levels(stratumcol),cex=.8, col = levels(stratumcol), pch =15, lty = 0)
```

Comment: What I did was removing the "levels()", which solved the problem, but caused a new one --> Repeating of my factor all 130 times, instead of legend just showing the 23 levels once.
#####
I tried solving it like you suggested @Richard Telford, but adding col = levels(stratumcol) returns an error: "invalid colorname 'EarlyDryPoor'", and no legend is displayed whatsoever.

Comment: I may have to manually define the legend based on the order they appear in the factorcolumn, even though I'd rather not do that on all my factors...

Comment: OK, I've misunderstood how your data are arranged. How have you specified the colours? With a palette? If so col = 1:23 will work.

Comment: Yes, I have a palette defined with 23 colors, so those does not repeat themselves - well, they do when the level they are assigned to repeats itself in the legend.
##### So my original problem that the legend did not show the right color corresponding to the plot has been solved. The solution just created a new problem: the legend now lists the levels in the order they appear in the factor - showing all 130 points and their respective level, not just the 23 levels (which is what usually happens).
### unfortunatly col = 1:23 didn't solve the repetition issue. Thanks for giving ideas!

Comment: I found a solution!
Thanks for solving my original problem @Richard and @DeveauP!

The solution to my subsequent problem I will post in my question as edit:)